# What is the corrent way to 'build' Angular v5 with angular -cli for production environment?

Tags: angular5, angular-cli

What is the corrent way to 'build' Angular v5 with angular -cli 6.0.8
for production environment?

This is my script

> npm script

```
ng build  --env=prod --prod --output-hashing=all --aot --sourcemaps --build-optimizer
```